Why is the residue at 0 not contributing to contour integral around unit circle?
Consider the following integral:
$$
I = \int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{1}{\pi}d x\frac{ \cos (m x) }{a-2\cos(x)},
$$
with ${\rm Re}(a)>0$ and $m$ a positive integer.
Writing the $\cos$ in the exponential form and changing variables: $z=e^{ix}$, the integral can be represented as a contour integral around the unit circle:
\begin{equation}
    I =  \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{1}{\pi} d z\frac{1}{2 \mathrm{i}z}\frac{ z^{m}-z^{-m} }{a-z-z^{-1}}.
\end{equation}
The only poles inside the unit circle are at $z=0$ and $z=(a-\sqrt{a^2-4})/2$.
However, when I check numerically, only the residue at $z=(a-\sqrt{a^2-4})/2$ contributes... E.g. for $m=2$ and $a=\sqrt{5}$  I obtain $I=-\sqrt{5}+3$ which also equal to $2\pi \mathrm{i}$ times the residue at  $z=(a-\sqrt{a^2-4})/2$...
Why does the residue at $z=0$ not contribute?

You made a sign error in the substitutions. You should get
$$\cos mx=\frac12(z^m+z^{-m}).$$
And for the function
$$
f(z)=\frac{z^2+z^{-2}}{z(\sqrt5-z-1/z)}
$$
Mathematica gives residue $3$ at $z_0=(-1+\sqrt5)/2$ and residue $-\sqrt5$ at $z_0=0$, so all is good.

Well, that was simple... Had I paid more attention this would have avoided a stackexchange post. Thanks for pointing it out!

Happens to us all :-) But, yeah, learning to "debug" is a skill mathematicians also have a lot of use of. Back in the day I would not have enjoyed calculating those residues with paper & pencil. I once filled 9 pages of a notebook to calculate a residue at a pole of order five that I needed for a quantum mechanics problem. Imagine the look on my face, when a fellow student (a physics major) presenting the problem on the chalkboard, at a criticial step referred to tables in Gradshtein-Ryzhik (sp?).

@JyrkiLahtonen are you talking about this formula $$C_{-1} = \frac{1}{(k-1)!} \frac{d^{k-1}}{dz^{k-1}} ((z-z_0)^k f(z))$$ where $f$ has pole at $z_0$ of order $k$? Yeah, Gradshtein-Ryzhik should be in every student's arsenal :)

Except for $a=2$ the denominator of integrand is not zero at $x=0.$ If $a=2$  the denominator has the form $2\ (1-\cos x) = 4\ \sin(\frac{x}{2})^2$ generating a pole $x^{-2}$.
Your substition $$e^{i x} = z, i e^{i x} dx = dz$$ produces a denominator of
$$\frac{i \left(z^{-m}+z^m\right)}{2 z \left(a-z-\frac{1}{z}\right)}$$
as
$$-2 i \left(a z-z^2-1\right) z^m$$
with poles at $$\frac{1}{2} \ \left(a \pm \sqrt{a^2-4}\right)$$
Only for $m=1$ there is an additional residuum at $z=0$. Poles of integer $m\ne 1 $,  $z^{-m}$ dont contribute
Just by playing around with NIntegrate (Mathematica yields the wrong result 0 for the algebraic form), I found
$$\text{Assuming}\left[u>0,\frac{2}{\pi }\  \int_0^{\pi } \frac{\cos (5 x)}{2 \cosh (u)-2 \cos (x)} \, dx\right]  \ = \ e^{-5 u} \text{csch}(u)$$
For $a<2$ there is a simple pole on the real axis, so the $\cosh u$ parameter makes sense.
$$\frac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{\cos m\ x}{2 \cosh u - 2 \cos x} \ dx = \frac{1}{e^{m\ u} \sinh u }$$

I am not sure I understand. Looking at the contour integral, there is a pole at $z=0$ due to the $z^{-m}$ term. Why does this have anything to do with the integrand being not zero at $x=0$??

They weren't deforming the integral. They were just rewriting the real integral as a parameterized complex integral over a closed curve, allowing the use of the residue theorem.

Why do you think that
$$\frac{z^{2m}+1}{z^m(az-z^2-1)}$$
would not have a pole at $z=0$ for all $m>1$? In the case $a=\sqrt5$ I checked out the residues at the origin when $m=2,3,4,5$ and they were all non-zero, so that pole will contribute.

Around $z=0$ (in some small disk) we can also expand the factor
$$
\frac1{1+z^2-az}=1-(z^2-az)+(z^2-az)^2-(z^2-az)^3+\cdots
$$
showing that we should always expect $1/z$ to have a non-zero coefficient?

You are right, the $z^{-m}$ term always finds his counterpart. in the infinite series.
